# Hadoop warning and error while copying to HDFS on Amazon Aws EC2

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hdfs

I am trying to setup Hadoop cluster on Amazon EC2. I was able to format namenode. The output of 'jps' command is following in the namenode:

5826 NameNode
6312 JobTracker
6192 SecondaryNameNode
8266 Jps

and in the slave node:

5452 DataNode
5699 Jps
5609 TaskTracker

So, I assume hadoop is running. While I am trying to copy data from local directory to HDFS with the command

> hadoop fs -mkdir /user/ubuntu/clusters
>
> hadoop fs -copyFromLocal clusters /user/ubuntu/clusters

I am getting data replication warning and other errors. The log is following

14/11/18 18:41:12 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/ubuntu/clusters/clusters could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1920)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:783)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

```
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:3023)
```

14/11/18 18:41:12 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: **Error** Recovery for null bad datanode[0] nodes == null
14/11/18 18:41:12 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Could not get block locations. Source file "/user/ubuntu/clusters/clusters" - Aborting...
copyFromLocal: java.io.IOException: File /user/ubuntu/clusters/clusters could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
14/11/18 18:41:12 **ERROR** hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to close file /user/ubuntu/clusters/clusters
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /user/ubuntu/clusters/clusters could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1920)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:783)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

```
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:3023)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Seems like your data node is running, but isn't talking to the namenode. Make sure that `fs.default.name` is set to your namenode address on your datanodes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Could you please tell me a little more about how can I set `fs.default.name` given I have multi-instance hadoop setup.


I have done the password-less SSH setup and I can access one instance from another. And using `$start-all.sh` command from Namenode, I was able to run the processes in Slavenode.

Comment: Have you read http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop ? Even though the page says it's valid for Hadoop 1.0, it still should work for HDFS 2. Make sure that the settings in `hdfs-site.xml` are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best step by step guide to create multinode cluster in Amazon EC2 is [**Here**](http://www.edureka.co/blog/install-apache-hadoop-cluster/)

It explains each and every step. You are already done with first part seems, Go through the second part which will help you..
Hope it helps you..

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will follow the tutorial and see whether the problem is solved or not.